# How can I display information on a form from two tables?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

This what my table relationships look like.

[image: Image 1]

This is what the form currently looks like. (Appointments)

[image: Image 2]

I want the form to automatically display First name, last name, age, telephone number and number of session. However, I do not want to rewrite the same fields present in "Patient Records" into the "Appointments" table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming whoever is using the form inputs the patient id, you can run a simple SQL query when that textbox has it's value changed, which would look something like this:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, Age, TelephoneNumber, SessionNumber
From Patient
Where PatientId = <inputted id here>
```

Replace the column names to match your db, and you can populate text to match the results as you see fit on your form.